# OpenCV multi-band blending assertion error

Tags: opencv, blending

i am new to OpenCV and want to apply multi-band blending in my code but getting the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (img.type() == CV_16SC3 || img.type()
>   == CV_8UC3) in cv::detail::MultiBandBlender::feed

````
    fixed = itk::OpenCVImageBridge::ITKImageToCVMat<InputImageType>(fixedResampled);
    moving = itk::OpenCVImageBridge::ITKImageToCVMat<InputImageType>(movingResampled);
    maskmoving = itk::OpenCVImageBridge::ITKImageToCVMat<InputImageType>(outputMask);

    cv::Point p;
    p.x = minX;
    p.y = minY;
    cv::detail::MultiBandBlender blender(false, 5);
    //feed images and the mask areas to blend
    blender.prepare(cv::Rect(p.x, p.y, moving.size().width, moving.size().height));
    fixed.convertTo(fixed, CV_16SC3);
    moving.convertTo(moving, CV_16SC3);
    maskmoving.convertTo(maskmoving, CV_8UC3);

    blender.feed(moving, maskmoving, cv::Point(p.x, p.y));```
````

Comment: How many channels do those input `Mat`s actually have?

Comment: @DanMašek one channel only

Comment: OK. Keep in mind that `convertTo` doesn't change the number of channels. Using things like `CV_16SC3` can therefore be misleading, especially when the `Mat` in question has different channel count. OpenCV just ignores the `C3` part anyway, so it's better to just say `CV_16S` in the first place. | Anyway, what the assertion tells you that the input image should be 3-channel. Convert the existing brayscale image to BGR using `cvtColor`.